# Turtlebot RaySensor race condition

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. When running turtlebot i keep getting a warning message

```
 Warning [RaySensor.cc:206] ranges not constructed yet (zero sized)
```

I understand from this [website](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/3/raysensor-race-condition) that it can be solved by moving a small part of the code upward. However, when I did a "locate" on the file RaySensor.cc, all the RaySensor.cc appears to be in the trash folder

```
chengxiang@ubuntu:~$ locate RaySensor.cc
/home/chengxiang/.local/share/Trash/files/gazebo-1.0.1/src/physics/bullet 
/BulletRaySensor.cc
/home/chengxiang/.local/share/Trash/files/gazebo-1.0.1/src/sensors/GpuRaySensor.cc
/home/chengxiang/.local/share/Trash/files/gazebo-1.0.1/src/sensors/RaySensor.cc
/home/chengxiang/.local/share/Trash/files/gazebo-1.2.0.1/src/physics/bullet   
/BulletRaySensor.cc
/home/chengxiang/.local/share/Trash/files/gazebo-1.2.0.1/src/sensors 
/GpuRaySensor.cc
/home/chengxiang/.local/share/Trash/files/gazebo-1.2.0.1/src/sensors/RaySensor.cc
/home/chengxiang/.local/share/Trash/files/gazebo-1.3.0.1/src/physics/bullet 
/BulletRaySensor.cc
/home/chengxiang/.local/share/Trash/files/gazebo-1.3.0.1/src/sensors 
/GpuRaySensor.cc
/home/chengxiang/.local/share/Trash/files/gazebo-1.3.0.1/src/sensors/RaySensor.cc
/home/chengxiang/.local/share/Trash/files/gazebo-1.4.0.1/build/src/sensors  
/CMakeFiles/gazebo_sensors.dir/GpuRaySensor.cc.o
/home/chengxiang/.local/share/Trash/files/gazebo-1.4.0.1/build/src/sensors 
/CMakeFiles/gazebo_sensors.dir/RaySensor.cc.o
/home/chengxiang/.local/share/Trash/files/gazebo-1.4.0.1/src/physics/bullet  
/BulletRaySensor.cc
/home/chengxiang/.local/share/Trash/files/gazebo-1.4.0.1/src/sensors 
/GpuRaySensor.cc
/home/chengxiang/.local/share/Trash/files/gazebo-1.4.0.1/src/sensors/RaySensor.cc
```

May i know how can i find the file or is there another way of solving this issue?
I am using ROS fuerte with Ubuntu 12.04. Thank you in advance.

update 1

An error occurs when launching turtlebot after i install from source using

```
rosws set simulator_gazebo --svn https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks
/simulator_gazebo/trunk
```

Error message :

```
[spawn_turtlebot_model-3] process has died [pid 7428, exit code 1, cmd  
/home/chengxiang/sim_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/spawn_model  
-unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model turtlebot  
__name:=spawn_turtlebot_model __log:=/home/chengxiang/.ros/log/277d87f4-1c4d- 
11e2-92d5-0017c4794a79/spawn_turtlebot_model-3.log].
log file: /home/chengxiang/.ros/log/277d87f4-1c4d-11e2-92d5-0017c4794a79  
/spawn_turtlebot_model-3*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45958/turtlebot-raysensor-race-condition/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2012-10-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've applied the patch [in Gazebo's fuerte branch](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/changeset/13ac178834e050883f647b5dfb1e4ea926d1db76).  Should be out in the next release.  Or you can try compiling simulator_gazebo from source.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-10-18**:
Thanks! I will compile it.

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-10-22**:
Sorry. May I know how do I compile it from source? I used : rosws set simulator_gazebo --svn https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk to install it from source, am I doing it right? After I did that, error came out when I roslaunch turtlebot.(Please see update 1).

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-10-29**:
Hi. Can anyone tell me how exactly to compile simulator gazebo from source? I used svn co to checkout (https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/simulator_gazebo-1.6.16/) and rosmake it. However, it didn't work and gazebo can't start. Anyone can enlighten me?